# When I build it I get an "expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'back' error

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class game;
@class MainMenu;
@interface gameOver : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIButton *paButton;

    IBOutlet UILabel *fScore;
    game *playagain;
    back *MainMenu;
    IBOutlet int hs;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *paButton;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil highScore:(int)highScore;

-(IBAction) playAgain;
-(IBAction) goBack;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared `back` anywhere. If it is an Objective-C class too, just add the following to the forward declarations:

```
@class back;
```